# How to grab the nearest object from a spherecast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Im using a Grab Object script that grabs a object that is inside the trigger collider.
But when i try to grab a object with more than 1 object inside the collider it grabs all the objects at the same time (example image with two bricks grabbed at the same time).

I need a rule to grab only the nearest object.

[two brick grabbed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HWy3.png)

im using this script to grab the objects.
Found it on a YT tutorial and tweaked it

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUp : MonoBehaviour {

    
    public float throwForce = 100;

    public bool canHold = true;
    public GameObject item;
    public GameObject tempParent;
    public GameObject poof;
    public GameObject vanish;
    public GameObject poofParent;
    public Transform guide;
    public bool isHolding = false;
    
    float distance;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
         
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

        distance = Vector3.Distance(item.transform.position, guide.transform.position);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        
        if (distance <= 6f)
        {
            isHolding = true;
            item.transform.position = tempParent.transform.position;
            
            //Poof
            GameObject myPoof = Instantiate(poof, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            myPoof.transform.parent = poofParent.transform;
            myPoof.transform.position = poofParent.transform.position;
            Destroy (myPoof, 2);
            
            //Particles
            GameObject myVanish = Instantiate(vanish, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            myVanish.transform.parent = tempParent.transform;
            myVanish.transform.position = tempParent.transform.position;
            Destroy (myVanish, 4);
        }

        if (isHolding==true)
        {
            
            item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
            item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().detectCollisions = true;
            item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
            item.transform.parent = tempParent.transform;
            item.transform.position = tempParent.transform.position;
            if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
            {
                Debug.Log("Trying to throw");
                item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(guide.transform.forward * throwForce);
                isHolding = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
            item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
            item.transform.parent = null;
        }
 }

}
```

Comment: There isn't actually a spherecast in the code that you've presented. You've already picked the item and only manipulate it. We need the code where the decision is made on what `item` is supposed to be.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very specific

I cant figure out how to implement the spherecast and the rule of the nearest object.

Searched some examples on google and youtube, tried it out but got only bugs :(

the logic is my head but i need some advice how to 

spherecast > array of objects > calculate the distance between objects/player > select the nearest object  and then how i can combine this with the PickUp script im already using.

maybe im asking too much hahah, but im an art director with not much experiencing in code. I can read, tweak and write simple scripts but i hit a wall here

Comment: Failed attempts are always welcome to see on SO. Makes it feel less like you're asking for freebie code.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sphere cast implemented in Unity's physics system, however it exists for a different purpose. Instead you're looking for [Physics.OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html)

Assuming that your `guide` object should be the center of the sphere you can determine the closest object (`closestSelectedObject`) in a specified selection radius.

```csharp
float radiusOfSphere;
float smallesDistance;
Transform closestSelectedObject;
/***/

void Update(){
  if(Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(guide.transform.position, radiusOfSphere);
    if(hitColliders.length > 0){
      smallesDistance = radiusOfSphere;
      foreach(Collider obj in hitColliders){
        float tempDistance = Vector3.Distance(obj.transform.position, guide.transform.position);
        if(tempDistance <= smallesDistance){
          smallesDistance = tempDistance;
          closestSelectedObject = obj;
        }
      }
      /*other stuff that your code does*/
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Will try to implement it.
thanks!

Comment: for comparison using `(obj.transform.position - guide.transform.position).sqrMagnitude)` would be better in performance than `Vector3.Distance` which basically equals using `(obj.transform.position - guide.transform.position). magnitude` which is more expensive as it has to take an additional square root ;)

Comment: If you want you could use `Linq` and do `var closestSelectedObject = hitColliders.OrderBy(obj => (obj.transform.position - guide.transform.position). sqrMagnitude).FirstOrDefault();` in a single line and then `if(closestSelectedObject){ ... }`

Comment: UPDATE >> Used the Linq suggestion and it worked! but now it is a global script so i needed to filter (if CompareTag) the Grabbable object with a Tag "CanPickup"

But now im figuring out how to keep the object grabbed, i messed up something and now it grabs the object and then immediately releases

Comment: @diegojms I would suggest that you open a new question for that. Infinite comment threads and 100 edits are simply too messy.

Answer (score 0):

my final functional (Update) code here
Cant make it without your help @derHugo, thank you!

```
void Update () {

    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(guide.transform.position, radiusOfSphere);
    var closestSelectedObject = hitColliders.OrderBy(obj => (obj.transform.position - guide.transform.position). sqrMagnitude).FirstOrDefault();
    
    GameObject grabbed = GameObject.Find("grabbedObject");

    if (grabbed != null)
    {
    Debug.Log("existe");
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !spaceDisabled) {
    spaceDisabled = true;
    }
    }

    else
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {

            // targetObject does not exist in the scene
            Debug.Log("NAOexiste");

                if (closestSelectedObject.tag.Contains("CanPickup"))
                {

                closestSelectedObject.transform.position = tempParent.transform.position;
                closestSelectedObject.transform.parent = tempParent.transform;
                closestSelectedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().detectCollisions = false;
                closestSelectedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
                closestSelectedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;

                originalName = closestSelectedObject.name;
                closestSelectedObject.name = "grabbedObject";
                
                //Poof
                GameObject myPoof = Instantiate(poof, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                myPoof.transform.parent = poofParent.transform;
                myPoof.transform.position = poofParent.transform.position;
                Destroy (myPoof, 2);
                
                //Particles
                GameObject myVanish = Instantiate(vanish, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                myVanish.transform.parent = tempParent.transform;
                myVanish.transform.position = tempParent.transform.position;
                Destroy (myVanish, 4);
                }
            }
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
                {
                Debug.Log("Q key was pressed.");
                
                grabbed.transform.parent = null;
                grabbed.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().detectCollisions = true;
                grabbed.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
                grabbed.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
                grabbed.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(guide.transform.forward * throwForce);          
                
                Input.ResetInputAxes();

                grabbed.name = originalName;
                
            }

    }
```